# vue js + firebase and [__ob__: Observer]

Tags: javascript, vue.js

help me please! i am using Vue + Vue-firestore. When i read data from Firebase cloud Database, i want to send this data to another page. But when i do it, i get "**ob**: Observer", but i want get array. what i should to do? ( P.S. if i use "product in products" - this works fine) . and second question - how i should better send data to another page, for example from product-list - to product-details with vue-router?

```
firestore() {
return {
  products: db.collection('products')
}
```

i get

```
[__ob__: Observer]
     0: {…}
 1: {…}
2: {…}
3: {…}
4: {…}
5: {…}
6: {…}
7: {…}
8: {…}
9: {…}
10: {…}
11: {…}
12: {…}
13: {…}
```

instead of this

```
Array(203)
[0 … 99]
[100 … 199]
[200 … 202]
length: 203
```

Comment: `__ob__: Observer` isn't anything to worry about. That's just something that gets added to arrays when Vue makes them reactive. If you're getting `[__ob__: Observer]` in your console logs that suggests the array is empty at the point you logged it. If the array has something in it you'd typically see that before the `__ob__: Observer` part.

Comment: Thx for respond! so, if i understood right - when i try log my array, it have not  loaded yet. and after sec later i can see it in vue-devtool.. So how can i get one product from list of products  ( for example i sent with router params id of product)? in that moment he doesnt exist yet . i tried load it with async function, but same problem

Comment: ok, i solved it with promise(resolve,reject)...Thx

Comment: hy @ВладимирЯкименко do you mind posting your solution